# Refer output to hashtable : Error Handling

Tags: python, python-3.4

How can i handle the error if the key is not available in eqType 
i mean like if its not in the eqType dict then return the `equip['type']` value

```
eqType ={
    10023: 'ONT-SFU',
    10040: 'OLT1T3',
    10048: 'OLT1T1',
    10050: 'OLT1T0',
}

extend = 'Name:', equip['name'] \
        , "\n" 'Desc:', equip['description'] \
        , "\n" 'Serial:', equip['serialNumber'] \
        , "\n" 'SWversion:', equip['swVersion'] \
        , "\n" 'Admin:', admstate[equip['admin']] \
        , "\n" 'Type:', eqType[equip['type']]

print(*extend)
```

Comment: Please simplify your question by removing code that is not directly related to the problem (make [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Is this a Passive Optical Network? :) Why not use `eqType.get(equip['type'], equip['type'])`?

Comment: @urban Yes, its for a PON :), Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
x = eqType.get(equip['type'], equip['type'])
```

The optional second parameter allows you to specify a default value to return if the key is missing.

If your dictionary only contains "truthy" values, you can also do:

```
x = eqType.get(equip['type']) or equip['type']
```

You can also use try/except, but not in a single line:

```
try:
    x = eqType[equip['type']]
except KeyError:
    x = equip['type']
```